# Error incomplete universal character name \U

Tags: c++, text-files

I'm trying to write a C++ program that alters a .txt file. However when I run it I get a strange error.

The error:

> 6:20 C:\Dev-Cpp\Homework6.cpp incomplete universal character name \U

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile ("C:\Users\My Name\Desktop\test\input.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    myfile << "This is a line.\n";
    myfile << "This is another line.\n";
    myfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Gah! WHY `using namespace std;`? *Bill goes to smash all introductory C++ textbooks.. (Not Anteater's fault, every into textbook does this for some reason...)

Comment: I don't personally see a problem with `using namespace`...except in header files.  OTOH, I do see a problem with Windows-path conventions rather than  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm

Comment: @Billy:  Because it's convenient.  Especially for small programs that don't use anything beyond the standard library.

Comment: @PigBen: Until that same beginner defines a function called `copy` and wonders why it won't compile

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`"C:\Users\My Name\Desktop\test\input.txt"`
The backslash (`\`) is a special character. You must escape it:
`"C:\\Users\\My Name\\Desktop\\test\\input.txt"`.

EDIT: Alternately, use forward slashes (`/`). Windows doesn't care.

Comment: @JaimeCervantes: Given that Mac or Linux wouldn't recognize a path like "C:/foo/bar" I don't see how that's relevant.

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape your backslashes in the filename.  In C++ string constants, backslash is an escape character which doesn't represent itself.  To get a literal backslash, you need to use a double backslash `\\`.

`\U` is the prefix for a 32-bit Unicode escape sequence: you'd use something like "`\U0010FFFF`" to represent a high Unicode character.  The compiler is complaining that `\Users...` is not a valid Unicode escape sequence, since `sers...` is not a valid hexadecimal number.

The fix is to use the string `"C:\\Users\\My Name\\Desktop\\test\\input.txt"`.

Comment: Well, `\U` means that in C++0x only. In the current standard (C++03) it means nothing. And it's only valid in a unicode character string. Given that the OP is using DevCPP, which comes with an extremely old version of GCC, I doubt that it supports C++0x.

Comment: We all missed the opportunity to congratulate him on using Unicode so early in his programming career.

Comment: Oops, I meant MinGW not GCC (but MinGW is GCC underneath)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use double backslashes there.  So `"C:\\Users...`.  Otherwise you're starting an escape sequence (in this case \U for a unicode literal).

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `\` with an extra `\` in the file name . (i.e. you need to use `\\`)

Answer (score 2):

it is exact case but, `\U` is not same meaning with `\u`. iOS accepts `\u` and it complains to `\U`

Answer (score 0):

This error happens even in Visual Studio 2015 even if the text is in ***comments*** of your C/C++ source. Visual Studio is not smart enough to ignore this text in comments, even if the command is telling something useful (e.g. in the word domain\user and if this text is literally expected in e.g. a configuration file). Weird.