# Audiere incomplete universal character name \U Error

Tags: c++, qt

Hey so I'm trying to make a music player using QT and Audiere. First I installed Audiere and put the header file in the compiler's include folder. Then I added the .lib file to the QT project. I wrote the following code:

```
AudioDevicePtr device(OpenDevice());
if(!device){
//failure
}
SampleSource* source = OpenSampleSource("C:\Users\Amenechi\Downloads\LMFAO - Sexy And I Know It");
OutputStreamPtr stream(OpenSound(device,source,true));
if(!stream){
//failure
}
stream->setRepeat(true);
stream->setVolume(0.5f);
stream->play();
```

But I get this error:

http://s20.postimage.org/u1yxk0d0s/Untitled.jpg

Now I'm not sure where it went wrong, maybe i installed the audiere library incorrectly?

EDIT:
Hey here's the compile output if that helps.

```
07:37:45: Running steps for project QTunesV2...
07:37:45: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
07:37:45: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/QTunesV1/QTunesV2-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
g++ -Wl,-subsystem,windows -mthreads -o debug\QTunesV2.exe debug/main.o debug/mainwindow.o debug/moc_mainwindow.o  -lmingw32 -lqtmaind -LC:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/QTunesV1/QTunesV2/../../ -laudiered -LC:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib -lQt5Widgetsd -lQt5Guid -lQt5Cored -llibEGLd -llibGLESv2d -lgdi32 -luser32 
c:/qt/qt5.0.1/tools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -laudiered
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.Debug:80: recipe for target 'debug\QTunesV2.exe' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\QTunesV2.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Qt/Qt5.0.1/Tools/QtCreator/bin/QTunesV1/QTunesV2-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug'
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
makefile:34: recipe for target 'debug' failed
07:37:45: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project QTunesV2 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.1 MinGW 32bit)
When executing step 'Make'
```

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes in the string, i.e. \\ instead of \.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help altering a text file with C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084283/help-altering-a-text-file-with-c)

Comment: Hey thanks I'm no longer getting the incomplete universal character error but I'm getting a collect2.exe error now?