# Unable to Execute script starting with Character 'U'

Tags: c, bash, shell, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have the below code snippet which executes a script through C program.

```
char upgrd_bb[512] = "";    
    sprintf(upgrd_bb,"/usr/bin/./\UPGRD_BB_ALL '%s'", path_argv[5]);
    if(!(system(upgrd_bb)))
    {
    dw_flag = 0;
    printf("Unable to Upgrade BB ");
    }
```

During Cross-compilation i get error

```
/home/ubuntu/Documents/FileOper.c:829:14: warning: universal character names are only valid in C++ and C99
/home/ubuntu/Documents/FileOper.c:829:14: error: incomplete universal character name \U
make: *** [/home/ubuntu/Documents/FileOper.o] Error 1
```

If i am changing the name of the script to any other character it compiles fine. can any one focus on this.

thanks in advance !!

Comment: Why did you insert the backslash in the string? Backslash is a technique in C strings to allow specifying non-printable characters, characters with explicit code, and so on. Simply remove it and, I guess, all will work.

Comment: UPGRD_BB_ALL is a shell script without extension. if i have to trigger this script i have use the concept of regex i.e in the end this leads to ./UPGRD_BB_ALL. if i dont use \ after / it looses its meaning.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084283/error-incomplete-universal-character-name-u)

Comment: I can't catch what you mean for "regex". You shall pass only final string to system(), not any intermediate values. If you missed some code, and this backslash is used as a character, you should double it to pass properly in the C string: e.g. `"\\"` is a string of the single backslash character.

Comment: The `\U` is an escape sequence in C; it expects a unicode definition after it, e.g. `\U24ff`.

Answer (score 2):

In the string

```
"/usr/bin/./\UPGRD_BB_ALL '%s'"
```

You have the sequence `\U`, which is being treated as a Unicode escape sequence. If you delete the extra backslash to get

```
"/usr/bin/./UPGRD_BB_ALL '%s'"
```

then you should be all set.

On the other hand, if you need the extra backslash in the name, then escape it:

```
"/usr/bin/./\\UPGRD_BB_ALL '%s'"
```

Hope this helps!